# How many people received stimulus (in the full amount) under the CARES act?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, stimulus

Looking at rules for he proposed new $600 stimulus checks passed by Congress (that Trump said is insufficient though), I see a lot of inclusion and exclusion criteria, [e.g.](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/money/2020/12/23/stimulus-checks-who-doesnt-get-stimulus-check-covid-19-relief-package/4013736001/)

> Many students, for instance, don't qualify. Neither do immigrants who don’t have a Social Security number. Some elderly and disabled people won’t get a check either, along with high-wage earners.

There's a gradual reduction in the amount for high wage earners, for instance. Also students and even minor children might not receive them depending on the parents' immigration status and tax claims. So it seems fairly difficult to say precisely how many people are going to receive them.

But since this is not the first stimulus like this, let me ask from the benefit of hindsight: how many people received CARES stimulus, and how many received the full amount under that law? Wikipedia has a [pretty long article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CARES_Act#Relief_to_individuals) on the latter, but I can't seem to find a simple answer in there on how many people actually got what. It only reports how much money was spent:

> After the enactment of the CARES Act, the Treasury Department and IRS disbursed about 160.4 million stimulus payments totaling $269 billion by the end of April 2020, of which nearly 1.1 million payments, totaling almost $1.4 billion (0.5% of the total value of all payments), were sent to dead people.

So how many (well... living) people actually got the full payment of $1,200? And how many $500 disbursements were made for dependent children? (That was the [max] for children under CARES, it seems.) Basically, is there a breakdown in terms of people as opposed to somewhat more abstract payments (which presumably sum entire families) of that CARES sum? (A simple division shows that the average payment/check was $1,681.25, but that surely covered more than one person.)

Comment: It's certainly the case that many students (and non-student dependent adults) didn't receive any money from CARES (and neither did their parents); the new law pending Trump's signature is not different in this regard.